# Is there a way to use a variable or user input to initialize an object in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an object representing a new user for my test program.

I want the name of the object to be the email address the user enters IE I want to be able to type in John@gmail.com.Classmethod()
however I cannot pass the value inside of the Email variable to the name of the new object variable. Please see code below

```
                        Console.WriteLine("Full Name:");
                        string name = Console.ReadLine();
                        
                        Console.WriteLine("Email:");
                        string email = Console.ReadLine();
                        
                        Console.WriteLine("Address:");
                        string address = Console.ReadLine();
                        
                        Console.WriteLine("Password:");
                        string password = Console.ReadLine();

                        Client NEWCLIENT = new Client(name, email, address, password);
```

To elaborate further I would like the string of the variable Email to replace the NEWCLIENT placeholder.

Thank you

Comment: This is not possible. The variable name has to be known at compile time, so you cannot create a variable with that name at runtime. You're going to need to find another approach.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense than your original question.  Thanks for taking the comments to heart.  Take a look at @Loocid's answer, I think it provides a path to what you want to do

Comment: I'm curious about the downvotes and the close votes.  Yes, it's not the most elegantly phrased question, but the OP is a newbie - and he took the comments on his original question to heart and came up with this version.  In addition, the answer provided by @Loocid meets his needs (I believe) and is a pattern that I've used over the years.

Comment: @Flydog57 you mean post by some "other" user - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69110580/how-can-i-use-a-variable-as-an-object-name-in-c-sharp?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Really! Two people asked the same question.  Homework, I guess.  Boy, they had me fooled.  I'm back to the bit-mine, lining up those ones and zeros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do that. The closest solution would be to use a dictionary with the email as the key like so:

```
var clients = new Dictionary<string, Client>();

// your code

clients.Add(email, newClient);
```

Then you can call your method with `clients["John@gmail.com"].Classmethod();`.

Comment: You can extend this even more.  Make the Dictionary a private static member of the Client class, and implement a public static indexer on that class.  You can also put the `Add` method for the dictionary in the class constructor.  Then you can access things this way: `Client["John@gmail.com"].Classmethod();`.  Of course, that has the downside that there's little the indexer can do except throw an `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception if the Client class doesn't recognize John@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand what You meant, but found no clear reason.

When You do

```
Client NEWCLIENT = new Client(name, email, address, password);
```

The object name is NEWCLIENT (should be newClient btw), NEWCLIENT can call
NEWCLIENT.ClassMethod();

You want name a variable dynamically, as far as I know it is not possible, as the compiler must be aware of all variables in order to associate them with a memory area.

Comment: Objects don't have names, variables do.